# Java - Sending serialized Objects over Socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I am programming a little simple multiplayer strategy game. Therefore I have a simple Connection class which sends different types of information as a String.

One type of a message has to be an ArrayList which has the current information of the playground.

My idea was to serialise the ArrayList in a String and then set the Identifier, which is a simple String, in front of it.

The problem is that the PrintWriter cuts the message and only sends a part of it.

```
public void SendGameInfo(Unit [][] gameStatus){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        s.writeObject(gameStatus);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.print("G: "+baos.toString());
    writer.flush();
}
```

And my initialization of the PrintWriter:

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(IP_Adress,PORT);
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        writer = new PrintWriter(osw);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't just blindly convert binary to a `String`. You'll end up with invalid content, bytes that are not valid for the encoding; then it breaks. Encode in Base64. Or, better yet, **don't use a `Writer`**. Use an `ObjectOutputStream` and the [`writeUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) method. A `Writer` is for character data, **never ever send raw bytes over a character stream**.

Comment: Thank you for the fast awnser. So I can use the `ObjectOutputStream` and write first the identifier and then I can write my Object with `writeObject()` and then flush everything. And if I only need to send Strings I simply use `writeUTF()` ?

Comment: Use `OutputStream` to construct `ObjectOutputStream` and write to it.

Comment: Yup. Send a `long` or whatever for the id then send the payload. `writeUTF` will be more efficient that sending a `String` as an `Object`.

Comment: Great thank you very much :)